# How to read only some form fields in php using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new at php and yii framework.can any one help me with my form.I have a update form which has 3 fields with drop down menu.how to make the from field value read only.it will be very much helpfull if any one provide me with code.here is my update form code:

Update form:

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'user_id',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'user_id'),
                        'dataProvider'=>$model->searchByUserId(Yii::app()->user->getId()),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>

    </div>
        <div class="row" id="jobTitle">
        <?php 
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition = "status= 'active'";
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'job_title_id',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => CHtml::listData(JobTitle::model()->findAll($criteria), 'id', 'name'),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select job title'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="file_name">
        <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
        $model,'file_name',
           array(
             'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
               'class'=> 'col-sm-5',
             ),
           )
            );

        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="statustype">

    <?php 
            $is_current = array('yes'=>'Yes', 'no'=>'No');
            echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
                $model,
                'is_current',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-5',
                    ),
                    'widgetOptions' => array(
                        'data' => $is_current,
                        'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select a status'),
                    )

                )
            ); ?>       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a value readonly - add `'readonly'=>true` to the options array of the field you want to make readonly.

For example:

```
<?php 
    $is_current = array('yes'=>'Yes', 'no'=>'No');
    echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
        $model,
        'is_current',
        array(
        'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'col-sm-5',
             ),
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'data' => $is_current,
            'htmlOptions' => array('prompt'=>'Select a status'),
         )
         'readonly' => true
         )
     );
 ?>
```

Comment: i can not make the file name field read only.'readonly' => true is not working.Can you be more specifics....Advance Thanks.... @Bfcm

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to set select element readonly. [With Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail) you can set it disabled and add value into hidden field using `unselectValue`.

```
echo $form->dropDownListGroup(
    // ...
    array(
        // ...
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'disabled' => 'disabled',
                'unselectValue' => $model->user_id,
            ),
        )

    )
);
```

Or use TbSelect2 it has `readonly` property.

Comment: @shopnil, the best thanks is `The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".`. ;-)

Comment: i disabled the form fields but now the problem is the  disabled field value is not saving in the database and not showing in the grid view..... @SiZE

Comment: If you provide `unselectValue` attribute to `dropDownListGroup`,  it will render a hidden field with it's value.